# using C#'s XmlReader on slightly malformed XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, malformed, xmlexception

I'm trying to use C#'s XmlReader on a large series of XML files, they are all properly formatted except for a few select ones (unfortunately I'm not in a position to have them changed, because it would break a lot of other code).

The errors only come from one specific part of the these affronting XML files and it's ok to just skip them but I don't want to stop reading the rest of the XML file.

The bad parts look like this:

```
 <InterestingStuff>
  ...
    <ErrorsHere OptionA|Something = "false" OptionB|SomethingElse = "false"/>
    <OtherInterestingStuff>
    ...
    </OtherInterestingStuff>
</InterestingStuff>
```

So really if I could just ignore invalid tags, or ignore the pipe symbol then I would be ok.

Trying to use XmlReader.Skip() when I see the name "ErrorsHere" doesn't work, apparently it already reads a bit ahead and throws the exception.

TLDR: How do I skip  so I can read  in the XML file above, using the XmlReader?

Edit:

Some people suggested just replacing the '|'-symbol, but the idea of XmlReader is to not load the entire file but only traverse parts you want, since I'm reading directly from files I can not afford the read in entire files, replace all instances of '|' and then read parts again :).

Comment: replacing | sign before loading a reader with - could solve the problem

Comment: How are you reading the info into the XmlReader? Are you reading from stream?

Comment: if you know the error in advance, can't you patch the content of the source before parsing it ? But in a general manner, you should correct the source xml.... or don't call it XML (I imagine you are dependant of someone else... ?)

Comment: Good suggestions, but I don't want to read in the entire file (hence why I use XmlReader and not XmlDocument.Load()) because this could be costly and I don't need all the info in the files. To clarify I read directly from disk using XmlReader.Creat(filepath) and yes I'm depending on other people, so I can't do anything about the source.

Comment: +1 Steve B - `XmlReader` reads Xml, so convert the non-Xml input to valid Xml in an isolated method, keeping the rest of your code clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've experimented a bit with this in the past.

In general the input simply has to be well-formed. An XmlReader will go into an unrecoverable error-state when the basic XML rules are broken. It is easy to avoid schema-validation but that's not relevant here.

Your only option is to clean the input, that can be done in a streaming manner (custom Stream or TextReader) but that will require a light form of parsing. If you don't have pipe-symbols in valid positions it's easy.

Comment: Hey Henk, this seems to me like the best solution. I also tried just loading the entire file and replacing the pipes but this made parsing take twice as long (even though I used a memory stream to store the loaded data). Extending a stream or TextReader seems like a good idea to keep being performant.

Answer (score 1):

`XmlReader` is strict. Any non-conformance, it will error.

So no, you can't do that unless you write your own xml implementation. Fixup on the malformed data is probably easier.

Answer (score 1):

Once I had a similar situation (with HTML files, not XML files). But I ended up using regular expression for each HTML file before entering it into my **operation pipeline**, to delete malformed parts. It came handy and was easier than struggling with the API. :)